# HTML form: use dl, dt, dd for laying out form inputs, but get distorted by a dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am doing a website. I have a form that has many elements. Many rows have two or three inputs in the same row.

I am using dl/dt/dd for placing form inputs in a row in the following way:

```
<form>

<div class="clearfix">
    <dl style="float: left;">
      <dt>Field name</dt>
      <dd><input type="text" name="myname" ></dd>
    </dl>
    <dl style="float: left;">
      <dt>Field name</dt>
      <dd><input type="text" name="myname" ></dd>
    </dl>
</div>
....
many other rows withe same structure layout of inputs.

</form>
```

On the left-side of my screen, I am using a menu such as the one on this page (I recently bought this theme). The menu is in a div with float:left. The form is on the right side positioned with margin-left: 200px.

The strange thing is that there is ONE big gap of space that separate rows into two groups. If I open and close a menu item, the lower group of rows moves up and down accordingly. Here is the screenshot:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/31887466@N03/9162373253/lightbox/

If I have one input element each row in the following way:

```
<form>

<div>
    <dl>
      <dt>Field name</dt>
      <dd><input type="text" name="myname" ></dd>
    </dl>
</div>
....
many other rows withe same structure layout of inputs.

</form>
```

There is no problem.

What is the cause of this strange behavior in the first layout design? How to fix this? I hope to use this way of layout form elements.

I am using Bootstrap 2.3.2.

Thanks and regards!

Cheers!

**----Update------**

I was suggested to not to use float because of my using bootstrap. Here is my new way of laying out form input elements on the same row. I have many similar rows. However, I still get the same problem:

```
<div class="controls controls-row">
    <dl class="span4">
        <dt><label for="website">Website</label>
            <input type="text"  class="input-xlarge" name="website" id="website">           
        </dt>
        <dd class="fieldErr">error message </dd>
    </dl>  
    <dl class="span4">
        <dt><label for="website">Website</label>
            <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="website" id="website">            
        </dt>
        <dd class="fieldErr">error message</dd>
    </dl>   
</div>
```

**---- Update 2 ----**

I tried the "multiple gird inputs per line", as suggested by bootstrap

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html

, I still got the same display issue:

```
<div class="controls controls-row">
  <input class="span4" type="text" placeholder=".span4">
  <input class="span1" type="text" placeholder=".span1">
</div>
```

(repeat many rows of the above structure)

**---- Update 3 ----**

The following two structures are not working either:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
        <dl>
            <dt><form:label path="website" >111<spring:message code="label.website"/></form:label>
                <form:input path="website" class="input-xlarge"/>           
            </dt>
            <dd class="fieldErr"><form:errors path="website"/></dd>
        </dl>       
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <dl>
            <dt><form:label path="website" >111<spring:message code="label.website"/></form:label>
                <form:input path="website" class="input-xlarge"/>           
            </dt>
            <dd class="fieldErr"><form:errors path="website"/></dd>
        </dl>   
    </div>
</div>


---------------

<div class="row">
  <div class="span8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span4">
                <dl>
                    <dt><form:label path="website" >111<spring:message code="label.website"/></form:label>
                        <form:input path="website" class="input-xlarge"/>           
                    </dt>
                    <dd class="fieldErr"><form:errors path="website"/></dd>
                </dl>   
      </div>
      <div class="span4">
                <dl>
                    <dt><form:label path="website" >111<spring:message code="label.website"/></form:label>
                        <form:input path="website" class="input-xlarge"/>           
                    </dt>
                    <dd class="fieldErr"><form:errors path="website"/></dd>
                </dl>         
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are using bootstrap then don't use clearfix hacks and especially don't float your elements.  See usage for bootstrap lists here http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html

Comment: phillip, I need to put two or more input elements in the same line. Each element has no fixed length. floating my elements is really a convenient way.

Comment: With bootstrap you don't do that.  You have a grid layout and you will add classes to your div span2 span3 etc...  Examples are on their site under scaffolding.

Comment: phillip, I updated my post and used a Bootstrap approach. I still get the same display issue. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span9">
    Level 1 column
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span6">Level 2</div>
      <div class="span3">Level 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You should put a dl in the div span6 and a dl in the div span3.  Feel free to reformat afterwards.

Comment: phillip, I tried the above structure and a variant. None of them is working. I still see that gap. Thanks for helping me out on this!

Comment: I will make a fiddle on jsfiddle.net ASAP but I'm on my ipad at the moment and limited functionality.

Comment: phillip, thanks so much for your kind help. Here is the screenshot of the unwanted space. http://www.flickr.com/photos/31887466@N03/9162373253/lightbox/. If I click the Settings menu, then the inputs in the lower group will move further down.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot explain it, but I wrapped my form inputs into a few fieldsets. Then the display is ok. I have a few sections in a form and each section uses a fieldset. This is strange, but works.

Hope this helps someone else.

Cheers.